# Limit integral switch for nondecreasing functions

Tags: convergence-divergence, monotone-functions

I have a sequence of functions $f_n:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ converging pointwise to a continuous function $f$.

If every $f_n$ is nondecreasing [$f_n(x) \leq f_n(y)$ for $x < y$] then can it be shown that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_a^b f_n = \int_a^b f$$

I thought of monotone convergence or dominated convergence theorems but I don't have $f_n$ increasing with $n$ and I can't be sure $|f_n(x)| < |f(x)|$. In fact I don't even know where $f$ may be positive or negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can show, in this case, that the convergence is uniform and switching the limit and integral is permissible.

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$, for any $\epsilon > 0$  there is a partition where on each subinterval we have

$$\tag{*}-\epsilon/2 < f(x_j) - f(x_{j-1}) < \epsilon/2$$

Any $x \in [a,b]$ belongs to some subinterval $[x_{j-1},x_j]$. By pointwise convergence and monotonicity of $f$ (since $f_n \to f$ and $f_n$ is nondecreasing), there exists $N$ depending on $x_1,\ldots,x_j  \ldots$ and $\epsilon$ but not $x$ such that for $n > N$

$$f(x_{j-1}) - f(x_j) - \epsilon/2 < f_n(x_{j-1}) - f(x_j) \\< f_n(x) - f(x) \\< f_n(x_j) - f(x_{j-1}) < f(x_j) - f(x_{j-1}) + \epsilon/2.$$

Using (*) it follows that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in [a,b],$ and convergence is uniform.

Comment: Dini's theorem is not relevant here.  That has to do with sequences where $f_n(x)$ is monotonic with respect to $n$ for each fixed $x$.   Here the functions are monotonic with respect to $x$ for each fixed $n$.

Comment: I noticed that my comment was nonsense and hence deleted it (not fast enough, apparently).

Comment: Why does $N$ depend on $x_1,x_2,...$? Can you elaborate on the part after $n > N$?

Comment: Since $f_n(x_j) \to f(x_j)$ there is an $N_j$ so that if $n > N_j$ then $f(x_j) - \epsilon/2 < f_n(x_j) < f(x_j) + \epsilon/2$.  The partition has a finite number of points say $x_0,x_1, \ldots, x_p$.  Take $N = \max(N_0,N_1, \ldots N_p)$.

Comment: Then you can build the inequality chain using that $f_n$ is  nondecreasing to get $f(x_{j-1}) - \epsilon/2 < f_n(x_{j-1}) < f_n(x_j) < f(x_j) + \epsilon/2$. Finally add in $-f(x_j) < - f(x) < - f(x_{j-1})$